# Java stream reader blocks until end-of-stream

Tags: java, buffer, java.util.scanner, inputstream

Basically, I have written myself some InputStream (for further use as System.in), which accepts and consumes buffer loaded by Swing components.

NOTE: Print statements were inserted for debugging purposes.

The read() method:

```
@Override
public int read() {
    System.out.print("[READ] Querying buffer... ");
    while(this.buffer.isEmpty());
    int val = buffer.poll(); // Consumes the first element
    System.out.format("done - 0x%x\n",  val);
    return val;
}
```

Reading raw bytes from stream WORKS:

```
InputStream input = new TestStream();
int chunk = 0;
while(chunk != '\n') {
    chunk = input.read();
    System.out.format("Byte: 0x%x", chunk);
}
input.close();
```

Output:

```
[Read] Querying buffer... done - 0x4c
Byte: 0x4c
...
Byte: 0x a
```

The `0x a` is the NL character (Yeah I am on Unix like system)

It outputs consumed characters as the stream is supplied additional data, and blocks while not.

But this does NOT work:

```
InputStream input = new TestStream();
Scanner scn = new Scanner(input);
System.out.println("Line: " + scn.nextLine());
scn.close();
input.close();
```

This approach simply consumes all the available data in the input stream, and blocks until the end of stream ( read() returning -1 ) has been reached. Either it seems to completely ignore the NL character in the stream, or the NL is inserted into the buffer wrong way (I highly doubt it is the latter)

What do you think is the cause if the issue?

Comment: Scanner doesnt use `read()` method. It uses `read(byte[])`, did you override that?

Comment: No I didn't. I assumed it is handled properly by underlying implementation. Dumb me of yesterday. I get it now. Many thanks. You could definitely post that as answer.

Comment: Sorry, my previous statement was wrong. You dont need to implement `read(byte[])`. Can you include the code of `TestStream()`

Comment: I am not currently in reach of my dev machine, but I can post it here as soon as I get access to it. Hovewer, I can post what I remember. But your statement seems logical (maybe not `read(byte[])` but `read(byte[], int, int)` as it is more generic) and I will try to test it in my test environment. Meanwhile, it would be good to post your initial comment as answer as it is worth it, as it may help people in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

k5_ has already pointed out the answer in his comment:

> Scanner doesnt use `read()` method. It uses `read(byte[])`, did you override that?

But didn't rewrite it as answer so I did. All credits to him.